# R Console result in external folder

Tags: r

I was working on the ARIMA model, I got the following result on the R console:

```
ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 124.185
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 127.0279
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 126.831
 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : 121.4817
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : Inf

 Best model: ARIMA(0,1,0)                    

 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 125.6857
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 128.5824
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 128.4456
```

But I want the result to be stored in external folder automatically in the form of table like the following:

```
[![Model                    AIC
ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift 124.185
ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift 127.0279

ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 126.831

ARIMA(0,1,0)                        Inf

Best model: ARIMA(0,1,0)                        
ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift : Inf][1]][1]
```

the code that I have used to get the result;

```
data<-read.table(file.choose(), header=T,sep="",quote="")
library(forecast)
dat<-c()
Error<- NULL
for(a in 1:11){
  for(b in 1:5){
        for (c in 1:5){
               Data1<-data[(nrow(data)-9-2*(a-1)+(b-1)):(nrow(data)-10+(b-1)),] 
      }
#This selects test sets 1,2,3,4, and 5 years beyond the training set
      Data2<-data[(nrow(data)-10+(b+c)):(nrow(data)-10+(b+c)),]
      Data3<-data[(nrow(data)-11+(b+c)):(nrow(data)-10+(b+c)),]
      #Fitting autoarima model
       fitarima<-auto.arima(Data1$abun,trace = TRUE)
      muhat<-predict(fitarima,data=Data2$abun)
      muhat$pred<-as.numeric(muhat$pred)
      for (i in nrow(Data2)){
         Error[i]<-abs(muhat$pred-Data2$abun)
          dat<-rbind(dat,Error)
      }
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: try `tidy()` function from `broom` package

Answer (score 0):

You can take the output from the console and create a dataframe using `read.table()`. Then you can use the `gridExtra` package to create a table of the dataframe. Then use ```pdf() to export the table to pdf.

```r
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

rawdata <- 'ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 124.185
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 127.0279
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 126.831
 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : 121.4817
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : Inf

 Best model: ARIMA(0,1,0)                    

 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 125.6857
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 128.5824
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 128.4456'

df <- read.table(text = rawdata, header = F, sep = ":", col.names = c('Model', 'AIC'))

best <- df[6,]

df <- df[-6,]

hj <-  matrix(c(0, 0.5), ncol=2, nrow=nrow(df), byrow=TRUE)

x <-  matrix(c(0, 0.5), ncol=2, nrow=nrow(df), byrow=TRUE)

mytheme <- ttheme_default(core = list(fg_params = list(hjust=0,
                                                       x=0.1, 
                                                       fontsize=10)),
                          colhead = list(fg_params = list(fontsize=10, 
                                                          fontface="bold"))
)


pdf("arima_models.pdf", height=6, width=8.5, onefile = TRUE)
grid.table(df, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
pushViewport(viewport(y=.25,height=.5))
grid.table(best, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, theme = mytheme)
dev.off()
```

Here is an image of the output [image]

Comment: You're welcome. If this is what you were looking for upvote the answer to help future users with a similar question

Comment: I have a bit of an idea of what to do but I'm going to need to see the code to test my ideas. I would suggest marking this answer as accepted and then asking another question and putting your loop in the question as it's going to be more complex to scale my answer to your loop.  This makes it easier for both of us to prevent us going back and forth in the comments. You might even get answer from someone else.

Comment: Add the loop into the question at least so that I can test it, even if it's minimal, as long as it can scale to your data.

Comment: I've decided to add another answer rather than edit my original answer, since the question has changed slightly.

Comment: is that for the tables or the text files or both?

Comment: but the arima function is outside the 3 for loop with the c, so how would it be output1-1-1? Wouldn't it be output1-1?

Comment: You can set up two counters, one for f, lets call it ```f_x``` and one for b, lets call it ```b_x```, then use ```paste0("output", f_x, "-", b_x, ".txt")```. Increment the counters inside their respective loop. So increment ```b_x``` inside the ```for(b...``` loop but increment ```f_x``` outside the ```for(b...```) loop but inside the ```for(f..``` loop.

Comment: Hahaha no worries man, an upvote and accept is more than enough appreciation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200175/discussion-between-mr-rlover-and-stackuser).

Answer (score 0):

What we are going to do is save the output that gets printed to the console to a text file and then read in the text files into R. We are going to use the `sink()` function to save the output to the console. Since the output gets printed at each iteration, we need to include `sink()` within the `for` loop. You can see in the `for` loop below that I've place two `sink()` calls around the `auto.arima()` call. This is because this is the function that prints the output to the console. I've used `paste0()` to create a new name for the output at each iteration. The output gets saved as a text file in the format of "output 1.txt".

```r
library(forecast)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

dat<-c()
Error<- NULL
x <- 1
for(f in 1:11){
  for(b in 1:5){
    for (c in 1:5){
      Data1<-data[(nrow(data)-9-2*(f-1)+(b-1)):(nrow(data)-10+(b-1)),] 
    }
    #This selects test sets 1,2,3,4, and 5 years beyond the training set
    Data2<-data[(nrow(data)-10+(b+c)):(nrow(data)-10+(b+c)),]
    Data3<-data[(nrow(data)-11+(b+c)):(nrow(data)-10+(b+c)),]
    #Fitting autoarima model
    sink(paste0("output", " ", x, ".txt"))
    fitarima<-auto.arima(Data1$abun,trace = TRUE)
    sink()
    x <- x + 1
    muhat<-predict(fitarima,data=Data2$abun)
    muhat$pred<-as.numeric(muhat$pred)
    for (i in nrow(Data2)){
      Error[i]<-abs(muhat$pred-Data2$abun)
      dat<-rbind(dat,Error)
    }
  }
}
```

Once the `for` loop is complete, we import the files into R. We get a list of the files using `list.files()`, which searches the working directory for files with the file extension of '.txt'. We use `lapply()` on `read.table()` to create a list of dataframes containing the arima models for each iteration. Then we simply loop through each object in the list and create plots of the data frame and then save it. This is the same as before, I've just created a loop to do this for each dataframe. The best model is saved in the last row of every dataframe, so this is convenient to extract using `nrow(mod)`.

```r
files <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = ".txt")
arima_mods <- lapply(files, read.table, sep = ":", header = FALSE)

j <- 1

for (mod in arima_mods) {

  df <- mod[-nrow(mod), , drop = FALSE]

  best <- mod[nrow(mod), , drop = FALSE]

  colnames(df) <- c('Model', 'AIC')

  hj <-  matrix(c(0, 0.5), ncol=2, nrow=nrow(df), byrow=TRUE)

  x <-  matrix(c(0, 0.5), ncol=2, nrow=nrow(df), byrow=TRUE)

  mytheme <- ttheme_default(core = list(fg_params = list(hjust=hj,
                                                         x=x, 
                                                         fontsize=10)),
                            colhead = list(fg_params = list(fontsize=10, 
                                                            fontface="bold"))
  )


  mod_num <- paste0('arima_fit', j, ".pdf")

  pdf(mod_num, height=6, width=8.5, onefile = TRUE)
  grid.table(df, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
  pushViewport(viewport(y=.25,height=.5))
  grid.table(best, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, theme = mytheme)
  dev.off()

  j <- j + 1
}
```

Here's an image of one of the tables [image: tables]